# Distinguishing between an int and a double

Tags: c++, int, double, invalid-characters

I've searched for this answer, and no one seems to know how to fix this error. I want the input to be strictly an int. If the input is a double, I want it to send an error.

```
int creatLegs = 0;
string trash;
bool validLegs = true;
do
{
    cout << "How many legs should the creature have? ";
    cin >> creatLegs;

    if(cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin >> trash; //sets to string, so that cin.ignore() ignores the whole string.
        cin.ignore(); //only ignores one character
        validLegs = false;
    }

    if (creatLegs > 0)
    {

        validLegs = true;
    }

    if (!validLegs)
    {
        cout << "Invalid value, try again.\n";
    }

} while (!validLegs);
```

It seems to almost work. It sends the error, but only after moving onto the next loop. How can I fix this? And why is it still showing the error message but still moving on before showing it?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not exactly sure what you mean. And no, it doesn't store it as an int. It doesn't know what to do if I type in something that is not an int. It spat out spam until I added the "if(cin.fail())"

Comment: cout << "\n" doesn't flush the output buffer whereas  cout << endl does.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should read data as string, and then check it char by char to verify that it is integer - if every char is a digit, then we have integer and we can parse it.

Problem with streams is, that if you're trying to read integer but decimal is passed, it reads the number up to the dot. And this part is a proper integer, so `cin.fail()` returns `false`.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int creatLegs = 0;
    bool validLegs = true;
    do
    {
        cout << "How many legs should the creature have? ";
        string input;
        getline(cin, input);

        validLegs = true;
        for (string::const_iterator i = input.begin(); validLegs && i != input.end(); ++i) {
            if (!isdigit(*i)) {
                validLegs = false;
            }
        }

        if (!validLegs)
        {
            cout << "Invalid value, try again.\n";
        } else {
            creatLegs = atoi(input.c_str());
        }

    } while (!validLegs);

    cout << creatLegs << endl;
}
```

This of course is not a perfect solution. If there any leading or trailing spaces (or any other characters like `+` or `-`), the program will fail. But you always can add some code to handle those situations, if you need to.

Comment: I tried voting up but it said my reputation wasn't high enough so I assumed that I couldn't accept answer either. My bad, I have to get used to the site. Thank you though!

Answer (score 2):

An input can be something else than a *representation* of an integer or of a floating point number.

Remember that numbers are not their representation(s): `9` (decimal), `017` (octal, à la C), `0b1001` (binary, à la Ocaml), `IX` (Roman notation), `8+1` (arithmetic expression), `neuf` (French) are all representations of the same number nine.

So you have to decide if you accept an input like `9   x`, or `9`  (with several spaces after the digit), ... More generally you have to define what are the acceptable inputs (and if the input is ending at end of line or not, if spaces or punctuation should be accepted, etc...).

You could read an entire line (e.g. with [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)) and use e.g. [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) (where the `%n` control format is useful, and so is the item count returned by `sscanf`) or [std::stol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (where you use the end pointer) to parse it

Notice also that the phrasing of your question ("Distinguishing between an int and a double") is wrong. There is no single "`int` or `double`"  type in C++ (but `int` is a scalar type, and `double` is a scalar type in C++, and you could define a `class` with a [tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) to hold either of them). AFAIU, if you declare `int x;`  then use `std::cin >> x;` with the user inputting `12.64` the dot and the digits `64` after it won't be parsed and `x` would become 12.

Comment: I want to just stick with ints at the moment so that I can understand how this works. It would be better of me to include all of the different ways to say a number, but since this is just a simple program, I don't want to go too in depth. Thank you though. I'm not quit sure what you said at the last part. I'm new to coding in c++ and if you could dumb that down for me slightly, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please follow the links I gave you. I'm sure you'll manage to code by yourself. And understanding documentation is  a very important part of software development, so you need to learn how to read documentation. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

```
int creatLegs = 0;
do
{
    cout << "How many legs should the creature have? ";
    cin >> creatLegs;    // trying to get integer
    if(!cin.fail())      // if cin.fail == false, then we got an int and leave loop
        break;
    cout << "Invalid value, try again.\n"; // else show err msg and try once more
    cin.clear();
} while (1);
```

Comment: This won't reject `1.23` as input

Comment: That crashes my program when I type in a letter. The way I have it set up right now, it sends an error when a letter is typed.

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an accepted answer, however I'll contribute a solution that handles all numbers that are integral, even those that are expressed as a floating point number (with no fractional part) and rejects input that contains anything other than spaces following the number.

Examples of accepted values, these all represent the number 4:

> ```
> 4
> 4.
> 4.0
> +4
> 004.0
> 400e-2
> ```

Examples of rejected values:

> ```
> 3.999999
> 4.000001
> 40e-1x
> 4,
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool get_int( const string & input, int & i ) {
    stringstream ss(input);
    double d;
    bool isValid = ss >> d;
    if (isValid) {
        char c;
        while( isValid && ss >> c ) isValid = isspace(c);
        if (isValid) { 
            i = static_cast<int>(d);
            isValid = (d == static_cast<double>(i));
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int creatLegs = 0;
    bool validLegs = false;

    do
    {
        string line;
        do {
            cout << "How many legs should the creature have? ";
        } while (not getline (cin,line));

        validLegs = get_int( line, creatLegs );

        if (creatLegs <= 0)
        {
            validLegs = false;
        }

        if (not validLegs)
        {
            cout << "Invalid value, try again." << endl;
        }

    } while (not validLegs);

    cout << "Got legs! (" << creatLegs << ")" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you want strictly integers (no decimal period and no scientific notation) then use this simpler *get_int* function:

```
bool get_int( const string & input, int & i ) {
    stringstream ss(input);
    bool isValid = ss >> i;
    if (isValid) {
        char c;
        while(isValid && ss >> c) isValid = isspace(c);
    }
    return isValid;
}
```